# How can I implement scroll in a DashboardLayout

Tags: android, scroll, dashboard

I'm using DashboardLayout provided by romannurik (https://gist.github.com/romannurik/882650)

This layout adapt children to fit on the screen and I want to implement a vertical scroll.
I want to keep the part to measure the max child per column but if children can't fit on the view I want to be able to scroll.

Can I have any leads to reach this goal ?

Answer (score 0):

Dashboards have sort of become defunct. If you expect there will be enough items that you can need to be able to scroll, then maybe you should just use a `GridView`.